# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se descargue un vídeo en un href, en google chrome?

Tags: html, video, chrome

tengo creado un espacio donde hay una imagen, si hacen click a esta imagen se les abrirá una pestaña nueva donde podrán visualizar un vídeo alojado en mi servidor. El problema es que en Chrome al hacer click, este vídeo se descarga y no lo visualiza como en Firefox.

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://midominio.com/images/documents/video.mov">
     <img class="thumbnailVideo" src="https://midomivio.com/images/documents/thumb3.jpg" alt="Video 3" width="320" height="auto"> </a>
```

Comment: El motivo por el que en chrome se te descarga y en firefox se reproduce es que en chrome necesitas un plugin para reproducir archivos quicktime; ya que desde las últimas versiones ha dejado de soportarlo. ¿Puedes cambiar la codificación del vídeo a otro formato aceptable por chrome y firefox?

Comment: Sí, tendré que investigar que formatos son los adecuados para estos navegadores. Gracias @ordago